# mysql Query fails in codeigniter, but works if run directly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, nested

Am trying to create a nested category system in codeigniter, based on http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

The below sql works fine if I use it straight in mysql. But if I use it as a query string in CI, I get a mysql error. Any clues ?

```
LOCK TABLE admin_category WRITE; SELECT @myRight:=`rgt` FROM `admin_category` WHERE `id` = 3; UPDATE `admin_category` SET `rgt` = rgt + 2 WHERE `rgt` > @myRight; UPDATE `admin_category` SET `lft` = lft + 2 WHERE `lft` > @myRight; INSERT INTO admin_category(name, lft, rgt) VALUES('AnotherCategory', @myRight + 1, @myRight + 2); UNLOCK TABLES;
```

part of the function in my model :

```
$qString = "
                LOCK TABLE $this->table WRITE;

                SELECT @myRight:=`rgt` FROM `$this->table`
                WHERE `id` = $prev_cat_id;

                UPDATE `$this->table` SET `rgt` = rgt + 2 WHERE `rgt` > @myRight;
                UPDATE `$this->table` SET `lft` = lft + 2 WHERE `lft` > @myRight;

                INSERT INTO $this->table(name, lft, rgt) VALUES('$name', @myRight + 1, @myRight + 2);

                UNLOCK TABLES;
                ";
$this->db->query($qString);
$inserted_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Thanks for reading ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running multiple queries at once which you cannot do unless you use functionality that specifically supports it (i.e. `mysqli_multi_query()`) which you almost certainly are not.

You need to run those queries separately for it to work with CI.

Comment: Thanks John, In other words, am I right in assuming that there is no way I can execute statements with multiple semi-cols in codeigniter ?